# Determining which recursive term is bigger if they share the same definition

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion, induction

We are given a recursive definition:

$a_1 = x,\\a_2=y,
\\a_n= c_1a_{n-1}+c_2a_{n-2}  \text{ for }n\ge3 $

where $x,y,c_1,c_2,n$ are natural numbers

we are to prove that $a_n \le c_3^n$ for all n

The base case is true

Assuming $a_k \le c_3^k$ is true

show $a_{k+1} \le c_3^{k+1}$ is true

---

We have:

1. $c_3a_k \le c_3^{k+1}$

and

2. $a_{k+1} = c_1a_k + c_2a_{k-1}$

where 1 can be written:

3. $c_1a_k + ma_k$

where $m+c_1 = c_3$

which can be rewritten:

4. $c_1a_k + mc_1a_k + mc_2a_{k-1}$

Now, 4 and 2 have the first term equal.

How can I determine whether $ mc_1a_k + mc_2a_{k-1}$ in 4  is bigger or not than $ c_2a_{k-1}$ in 2?

Comment: do you have any relation between $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ ? Or are you looking for an expression of $c_3$ using $c_1$ and $c_2$ that respect the inequality ?

Comment: $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are all constants. Yes I want them to respect the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c_3 = \max(1,x,y,c_1+c_2)$. Then
$$
a_1 = x \stackrel{c_3 \geq x}\leq c_3^1
$$
and
$$
a_2 = y \stackrel{c_3 \geq y}\leq c_3 \stackrel{c_3 \geq 1}\leq c_3^2.
$$

Now suppose that $a_{n-2} \leq c_3^{n-2}$ and $a_{n-1} \leq c_3^{n-1}$. Then
$$
a_n = c_1 a_{n-1} + c_2 a_{n-2} \stackrel{\text{assumption}}\leq c_1 c_3^{n-1} + c_2 c_3^{n-2} \stackrel{c_3 \geq 1}\leq c_1 c_3^{n-1} + c_2 c_3^{n-1} \stackrel{c_3 \geq c_1+c_2}\leq c_3^n.
$$

Comment: Note that $x$, $y$, $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ are natural numbers, then the "1" in the maximum is not needed. Also, $c_1 c_3 + c_2 \le c_3^2$ is more permissive than $c_1+c_2 \le c_3$.

Comment: The bound isn't optimal anyhow. The correct rate of growth is $O(c^n)$, where $c$ is the larger root of $c^2 = c_1 c + c_2$.

Comment: @John L., all these constants may be 0.